# Regex for 1 uppercase and 2 lowercase letters, 2 digits, and 2 non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to create a Regex for a string that contains **1 uppercase and 2 lowercase letters, 2 digits, and 2 non-alphanumeric characters**, for now I have:

```
(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[a-z]{2})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W{2})
```

The problem is that the chars must be tougher in this regex and that's not the case I need.

I need solution that accept:

```
Taa12@!
T1a1b@!
a1!b@2A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=(?:\w*\W){2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGUgGZ/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` - at least two digit chars (not necessarily consecutive)
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})` - at least two lowercase ASCII letters (not necessarily consecutive)
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - at least one ASCII letter
- `(?=(?:\w*\W){2})` - at least two non-word chars (not necessarily consecutive)